# Hair particles keeps rotating to global axis, instead of surface normals

Tags: particles, rigging

I´m making a character´s eyelashes and I want all the hairs to follow the surface normals. Even if I tweak all the rotation settings they keep following global coordinates when I rotate the character´s head for example. What could it be??
[image]

[image]

It has 3 particle systems and all of them have the same orientation problem when I move the rig. Th particle mods are after the armature modifier.
[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your particle settings?